# Player only moving forward for one tick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found this piece of code online

```
// Do not apply input if we are showing a level selection display
if(HaltUpdateMovement == true)
    return;

bool moveForward = false;
bool moveLeft    = false;
bool moveRight   = false;
bool moveBack    = false;

MoveScale = 1.0f;

// * * * * * * * * * * *
// Keyboard input

// Move

// WASD
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) moveForward = true;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) moveLeft    = true;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) moveBack    = true; 
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) moveRight   = true; 
// Arrow keys
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))    moveForward = true;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))  moveLeft    = true;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))  moveBack    = true; 
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) moveRight   = true; 

if ( (moveForward && moveLeft) || (moveForward && moveRight) ||
     (moveBack && moveLeft)    || (moveBack && moveRight) )
    MoveScale = 0.70710678f;

// No positional movement if we are in the air
if (!Controller.isGrounded) 
    MoveScale = 0.0f;

MoveScale *= DeltaTime;

// Compute this for key movement
float moveInfluence = Acceleration * 0.1f * MoveScale * MoveScaleMultiplier;

// Run!
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
    moveInfluence *= 2.0f;

if(DirXform != null)
{
    if (moveForward)
        MoveThrottle += DirXform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * moveInfluence);
    if (moveBack)
        MoveThrottle += DirXform.TransformDirection(Vector3.back * moveInfluence) * BackAndSideDampen;
    if (moveLeft)
        MoveThrottle += DirXform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left * moveInfluence) * BackAndSideDampen;
    if (moveRight)
        MoveThrottle += DirXform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right * moveInfluence) * BackAndSideDampen;
}
```

My problem is, I want my person to move forward without stop once I press w, but he only moves forward for a tick and then stops again, any ideas/help?

Comment: Does it work for the other directions? If so, replace `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))    moveForward = true;` with `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))    moveForward = true;`

It looks like `Input.GetKeyDown` might only be true if the key changes state from un-pressed to pressed, while `Input.GetKey` only checks if the key is in the down state.

Comment: but if i do that my player will only move forward if i press the button, i want to press the button once, and then he should start moving forward uncontrollably.

Answer (score 3):

Use `GetKey` instead of `GetKeyDown`. `GetKeyDown` only returns true *during the frame when the user pressed the key*, whereas `GetKey` will continue to return true as long as the key is held.

See: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

And: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Comment: but that's not what i wan't my player to do, i want him to move even though i don't press the button, i just want the w key to make him start going.

Comment: @user2511457 Then you need to add some additional state to your application; something that's remembered between frames. Add a boolean member variable "isMovingForward" which is set to true when up is pressed, and false when anything else is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `moveForward` set to `false`? It appears to be happening when it shouldn't. Or it's scoped wrong. Is it a local variable (i.e. declared within a method) or a field on the class (i.e. declared directly in the class)? The latter is probably what you're looking for.

```
bool moveForward = false;

void Update() // or whatever method you had your code in
{
    bool moveLeft  = false;
    bool moveRight = false;
    bool moveBack  = false;
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: right over the variables it says  `public virtual void UpdateMovement()
 {`

Comment: This is a good start, but then once the object starts moving you won't be able to stop it